# how to set v120xp in cmake with vs2013's NMake

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake, windows-xp, nmake

I'm using **win7-32bit** + **cmake** + vs2013's **NMake**.exe to build exe, I need the exe be able to run on WinXP, I know how to do that with vs2013 IDE(set the Platform-Toolset to v120xp), but I'm not using the IDE, I just use its NMake. This is how I generate the project file and exe:

```
build> cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
build> nmake
```

**Question 1**: In the CMakeLists.txt, how to set it use v120xp?

**Question 2**: Is it necessary to build all static lib with the v120xp? Or just the exe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting [CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html). It allows selecting the toolset for Genertors that support it. Generators that support Toolsets are Visual Studio and XCode.

Your call to CMake should look like this:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=v120_xp ..
```

**Update 1**: As pointed out in the comments NMake doesn't support Toolsets

Thes solution is to specify

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01")
```

for console applications, or

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01")
```

for windows applications.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it complains: `NMake Makefiles does not support toolset specification, but toolset v120xp was specified`. [this thread](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14146) says it only works with vs >= 10. I searched for this option and found some other option like `set(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET "v120xp")` also not working.

Comment: and followed the links I found [Targeting from the Command Line](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx). For short, just specify `SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01")` or 
`SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01")`

Comment: Correct cmake option would be -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=v120_xp (with underscore before "xp")